# TootlTip When mouse over the image

Tags: css, jquery-tooltip

I had  images, when i keep my cursor on the image a tool tip need to appear,How can i apprach that with simple code rather than complex

http://jsfiddle.net/Navya/RwBXB/2/

Answer (score 0):

In really simple code, it is:

```
<img src="yourimage.png" title="Your tooltip!" />
```

Comment: How can i use class and title in jquery, i got the code, but it is too big for simple ToolTip,

Comment: Hi i added title where i want tooltip to dispaly and a javascript url  **<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>**, now when i place a mouse over i can see tooltip but i want that tooltip in some circule shape rather than rectangular shape, how can i add that , do i need to add any css ?

Answer (score 0):

use this jquery plugin, its a clean and simple tooltip.
theres a guide how to implement it, so u shouldnt have any trouble, but i can provide additional help if needed.

http://code.drewwilson.com/entry/tiptip-jquery-plugin